# Building multiple framework support in Visual Studio by one solution per framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to support multiple TargetFrameworks in my Visual studio Microsoft.NET.Sdk project, but I want to make it so that I would have several solutions, where solution would determine which target framework it will compile.

Theoretically this can be done for example like this:

```
Directory.Build.props:

<Project>
    <!-- 
        TargetFramework is not defined at nuget restore phase - but we can define it.
        If solution name contains "netcore" - then solution aims to .net core.
    -->
    <PropertyGroup Condition="$(SolutionName.Contains('netcore'))">
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="!$(SolutionName.Contains('netcore'))">
        <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- nuget restore path must be different for different target frameworks, otherwise it will create mess between projects -->
        <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)obj\nuget\$(TargetFramework)\$(MSBuildProjectName)\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

and then to have two solutions, one for .net framework 4.7.2, one for .net core, where second solution filename should contain 'netcore' string in it.

This however will not work pretty in case if `TargetFramework` starts to vary also between `netstandard2.0` and so on...

Then it came to my mind - that maybe I could perform nuget restore for multiple frameworks, but just to compile project for one framework. I think `BeforeBuild` event could be used to differentiate build phase between nuget restore and build - so I wrote something like this:

```
test.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1;net472</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFrameworks>net472</TargetFrameworks>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="TargetFrameworks: $(TargetFrameworks)" />
  </Target>
```

But this does not work, build happens for two frameworks, not for one, like I've desired originally.

Of course `BeforeBuild` should be eventually executed for solution, which does not have `netcore` in it's name.

Maybe someone could propose better solution for this one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out.

So multiple solutions will not tolerate each other presence, and nuget restore directory needs to be overridden. Override can be done per solution basis, just to put things simple - just use solution name to define nuget restore path.

```
Directory.Build.props:

<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)obj\nuget\$(SolutionName)\$(MSBuildProjectName)\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

And individual projects then determine target framework, which they want to use, for example like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(SolutionName.Contains('netcore'))">
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="!$(SolutionName.Contains('netcore'))">
        <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>$(SolutionDir)obj\$(TargetFramework)-$(Configuration)\$(AssemblyName)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)bin\$(TargetFramework)-$(Configuration)</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="obj\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="obj\**" />
    <None Remove="obj\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

This will allow to have separate solutions, one for each target framework, but also will work correctly for nuget restore + build.

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.